# python script to extract phrases from an XML file

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file which contains these tags.

```
<?xml version="4.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phrases>
  <phrase title="bacd_dd" version_id="10" version_string="lphaf"><![CDATA[bacd dsfbsd dfsd]]></phrase>
  <phrase title="bcvd_ff" version_id="10" version_string="lphaf"><![CDATA[ans fkdfjid dfdf]]></phrase>
  <phrase title="bdsd_fffd" version_id="17" version_string="lphaf 7"><![CDATA[jdhfd dsfodf wernksdlg ffguywer 
<BR>
dsf
sddsfdsfdsf ksdfj fdsf]]></phrase>
</phrases>
```

Now i want to get only the tag values. How can i parse the whole XML file ?

Comment: use parsers like [elementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) [lxml](http://lxml.de/) [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `xml.etree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phrases>
  <phrase title="bacd_dd" version_id="1010010" version_string="1.1.0 Alpha"><![CDATA[bacd dsfbsd dfsd]]></phrase>
  <phrase title="bcvd_ff" version_id="1010010" version_string="1.1.0 Alpha"><![CDATA[ans fkdfjid dfdf]]></phrase>
  <phrase title="bdsd_fffd" version_id="1000017" version_string="1.0.0 Alpha 7"><![CDATA[jdhfd dsfodf wernksdlg ffguywer 
<BR>
dsf
sddsfdsfdsf ksdfj fdsf]]></phrase>
</phrases>""")

print root.tag
>>>'phrases'

for i in root:
    print i.text

>>>bacd dsfbsd dfsd
ans fkdfjid dfdf
jdhfd dsfodf wernksdlg ffguywer 
<BR>
dsf
sddsfdsfdsf ksdfj fdsf


for i in root:
    print i.attrib

>>>{'version_string': '1.1.0 Alpha', 'version_id': '1010010', 'title': 'bacd_dd'}
{'version_string': '1.1.0 Alpha', 'version_id': '1010010', 'title': 'bcvd_ff'}
{'version_string': '1.0.0 Alpha 7', 'version_id': '1000017', 'title': 'bdsd_fffd'}
```

**If need of parse from `xml` file**.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

For more refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: You have to use `python 2.5` or above. Also check any other `xml.py` file if any which overrides it.

Comment: Then rename it something xml1.py :)